Embedding multiple self-contained HTML widgets in a single HTML file
I'm trying to combine multiple html widgets displaying various data, which is for internal use. So the HTML file should be entirely self contained. I have been able to get this to work by calling on the files individually using an R script to generate the HTML file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<style>body{background-color:white;}</style>


</head>
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe src="C:\Users\vmo\Desktop\R_filer/widget_1.html" style="display:block" height="300" width="1200"></iframe>
    <iframe src="C:\Users\vmo\Desktop\R_filer/widget_2.html" style="display:block" height="300" width="1200"></iframe>
    <iframe src="C:\Users\vmo\Desktop\R_filer/widget_3.html" style="display:block" height="300" width="1200"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
</html>

In order to self-contain this in a single file, it seems to me I should be able to just replace the path specifications with the entire blocks of code that make up the individual widgets widget_1...3.html, but I have not been able to get this working. I tried the following, but it did not seem to work:
</head>
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe <source> **ENTIRE widget_1.html FILE PASTED HERE** </source> height="300" width="1200"></iframe>
    <iframe src="C:\Users\vmo\Desktop\R_filer/widget_2.html" style="display:block" height="300" width="1200"></iframe>
    <iframe src="C:\Users\vmo\Desktop\R_filer/widget_3.html" style="display:block" height="300" width="1200"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
</html>

Any suggestions?
